# All files and folders are not being listed in the imce file browser in Drupal 7

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, drupal, amazon-s3, drupal-7

I am using AWS S3 bucket to upload files, my problem is that all files and folders are not being listed in the file browser. In S3 bucket there are 10000 files but only 1001 files are being listed in the file browser.

What I have done already:

1) Set proper file and folder permission on AWS
2) Increase max_execution_time in php.ini more than 5 mins

Please suggest what to do next for this issue. Is there any pagination module for imce file listing.

Regards,.

Comment: Can anyone suggest something from where I can look into this, in IMCE module or S3 server?

Comment: I have found a solution, just commented out code of getting image height & width in imce module. Actually, this script is written in loop and hits to S3 bucket again & again.

Comment: Can you share the file name and code part that you commented out please?